# Cisco NAT problems (Packet Tracer)

Tags: networking, router, nat

I have a little problem with my NAT configuration. When I ping 2 separated PC or laptop, the ICMP packet does not "find" the route back to the source machine.

The NAT translate the IP when the package go to the Destination PC, but when go back the package loop between the three routers.

Anyone can help me what I suppose to be do with this?

Here is my network:

[image]

And here is my PKT file (if it helps):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7wly05y93u5ddse/NAT.pkt?dl=0

Comment: From which machine are you pinging from?

Comment: The problem same with all of them. When the package go back to the original source, it loop between the routers. (For example: Laptop0 -> Laptop4, the L4 receive the package, and send back, but the routers start loop it in cicrle.)